# celeryy server error: "cannot mix new setting names with old setting names" while running the server

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am using celery server with radis as a broker but when I am trying to run the celery server following error occur:

[image]
I am using following command to run the server : `celery worker -A app.celery --loglevel=info`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have picked up stale instructions that refer to old celery constant names. It's probably (and hopefully) just a matter of making sure you're using the new names. (The error suggests switching to the old names, if the code is going to be long-lived, using the newer names is preferable.)

See the "Note:" near the top of http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/configuration.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer I got ur point but how can I replace CELERY_INCLUDE to include.

Comment: Are you configuring celery yourself? That is, is there a `CELERY_INCLUDE` in your code? Or are you using a 3rd party package (something you installed via anaconda) that provides a layer on top of celery? If the former, make the change there. If the latter, you have a more interesting problem, and may need to change any new-style configuration that you're doing to be old-style.

Comment: I am using a 3rd party package(installed via anaconda). How can I do this "and may need to change any new-style configuration that you're doing to be old-style."

Comment: Sadly, there are times when software migrates on independent schedules and you find yourself stuck trying to get A working with B. Hopefully you're not in one of those spots. Which additional software are you installing?

Comment: Thanxx for the help. I somehow figure it. Here i use include :  " celery = Celery('coalition_python', broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'],include=['coalition_python']) " and now it's working.